# Medication order in Prescription table

Tags: mimic-iii

Can I know the med schedule in the Prescription table? For instance, one row indicates 'Hydromorphone 20mg vial is used for a patient' but I cannot find the detailed schedule.

20mg of of hydromorphone is lethal dose and it must have been ordered as something like '2mg PRN q3h' via CPOE, but I cannot find any dose scheduleing. Is there any way to get info regarding the detailed schedule doses?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look in either the `inputevents_cv` or the `inputevents_mv` table for detailed information about infusions. This will require identifying the one or more `itemid` associated with hydromorphone in the `d_items` table (also best to look for Dilaudid).